# pgfgantt and pdflscape - gantt chart drops a month

Tags: pgfgantt, pdflscape

I'm trying to produce a Gantt chart on a landscape page as part of a larger document. However, I when I compile the MWE below the last month unit (2020-06) seems to drop off the chart (image included below as well).

This seems unaffected by x unit but I've had to use it so that the chart fits on a page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=0.5mm,
  time slot format={isodate-yearmonth}
  ]{2019-07}{2020-06}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
  \ganttbar{Test}{2019-07}{2020-03}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Image:
[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pgfgantt` a time slot is usualy one day. With the option `compress calendar` it can be changed to one month. Adding this option solves your problem. But if you want to be able to have `\ganttbar`s, which start/end in the middle of a month, you have to use `time slot format={isodate}` and give complete dates (with day).

**Edit:**

The option `compress calendar` was introduced in version 4.0. Now version 5.0 is out. Here `compress calednar` is replaced by `time slot unit`,
which can have the values `day`, `month` or `year`. The old option is no longer available.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=15mm,
  time slot format={isodate-yearmonth},
  % use for pgfgantt version 4.0
  %compress calendar
  % use for pgfgantt version 5.0
  time slot unit=month
  ]{2019-07}{2020-06}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
  \ganttbar{Test}{2019-07}{2020-03}
\end{ganttchart}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=0.5mm,
  time slot format={isodate},
  ]{2019-07-01}{2020-06-30}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
  \ganttbar{Test}{2019-07-01}{2020-03-15}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I found that the 'compress calendar' option gave me an error when compiling. But using the full isodate has worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @ChasNelson: I just checked, `compress calendar` was introduced in version 4.0. So if you are using an earlier one, you have to update. But then you get version 5.0, and there this option is replaced by `time slot unit`, which can have the values `day`, `month` or `year`.

Comment: @ChasNelson: I updated my answer.